# Do I need to worry about "tail: unrecognized file system type 0xbeefdead"?

Tags: tail

I'm trying to follow a regular text file with `tail -f -n 50 filename`. I get the information from the file just fine, except I always get this error message:

> tail: unrecognized file system type 0xbeefdead

It happens on every file. The `0xbeefdead` worries me -- it looks like a hacker tag.

```
$ tail --version
tail (GNU coreutils) 8.4
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `0xdeadbeef` instead? `:P`

Comment: Probably obvious but 0xDEADBEEF is often used to indicate uninitialized bytes and things like that.   BEEFDEAD is probably a smartass twist on this.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak (search for deadbeef)

Comment: Incidentally, as a vegetarian, I am offended by `Oxbeefdead`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're getting this warning when using the StorNext filesystem and are running `coreutils` 8.21 or earlier, there isn't much to worry about; this warning message is expected.

GNU `tail` has hardwired knowledge about a number of filesystem types, and warns when it encounters an unknown type. Support for the StorNext filesystem was added to `tail` in `coreutils` in April 2013, and was released in `coreutils` 8.22. The commit is [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/e414ff4c4c3fe029a9702c9909bf4eccbef68c21). If you can't get that version of `coreutils`, or wish to edit and recompile the source yourself, here is the diff from that commit:

```
src/stat.c
@@ -399,6 +399,8 @@ enum
     return "selinux";
   case S_MAGIC_SMB: /* 0x517B remote */
     return "smb";
+  case S_MAGIC_SNFS: /* 0xBEEFDEAD remote */
+    return "snfs";
   case S_MAGIC_SOCKFS: /* 0x534F434B local */
     return "sockfs";
   case S_MAGIC_SQUASHFS: /* 0x73717368 local */
```

Comment: Why does a userspace program like `tail` need to be compatible with a specific filesystem? I guess what I mean is, is there no filesystem abstraction it can rely on?

Comment: @illuminÉ, the main reason for determining the filesystem type is the "tail -f" operation: the most efficient way to figure out if new data has been written to a file varies from one filesystem to another.

Comment: `tail` with the `-f` option uses `inotify` if it can. But `inotify` can only monitor changes caused by activity done by the local system's kernel. So `tail` will use `inotify` only if the file argument is on what it classifies as a "local" filesystem.

Comment: And the final missing piece of information is that the kernel gives no clear indication that anything is wrong when you try to use inotify on a filesystem that doesn't support it, so this magic number kludgefest is basically the only safe way to use it.